# Swiftui iOS 14 Toolbar

Tags: swiftui

iOS 14 provided a new `.toolbar` implementation for the NavigationView. There is a placement parameter with options of `.principal`, `.navigationBarLeading`, and `.navigationBarTrailing`.

I'd like to add a search bar in the Navigation bar. What is the proper way to achieve a fullwidth search bar?

My expectation was that I would be able to put the search bar on the left using navigationBarLeading and set the frame to full width.

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
        HStack {
            Text("Full width")
            Spacer()
            Text("Toolbar")
        }.frame(width: .infinity)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had similar in the bottomBar. Maybe you can try. Cheers

```
ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading){
    Spacer()
}
ToolbarItem(placement: .principal){
    HStack {
        Text("Full width")
        Spacer()
        Text("Toolbar")
    }
}
ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing){
    Spacer()
}
```

Comment: I am trying to make my bottomBar item take up the full width. How did you do it?